# Configure Binding on WCF Service injected with Autofac

Tags: wcf, binding, configuration, integration, autofac

I'm serving some WCF services using Autofac, and following the tutorials it's working fine! But now, I need to send a request of > 65Kb, so I must to change the binding on the server to allow this request, and I can't find how to do it!

How can I intercept the injection of the service in order to assign a binding created dinamically or defined in a .config? On the client side I've done correctly and is working fine!

Thanks in advance,

Marc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution, following [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/autofac/vPrvd0RtOtM/rmrjUvgrNj0J).

I've rewritten the config file using his configuration and my service names and it works. I tried it before, but it didn't work; sincerely I don't know where was my error.

The configuration:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="clearHttpBinding">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="largeMessageHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="10000000"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" messageEncoding="Text" transferMode="Buffered">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="10000000" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior" name="my.Services.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="largeMessageHttpBinding" contract="my.ServiceModel.ServiceContracts.IMyService"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you actually able to get metadata for your service? Mex binding is missing in your config. I cannot get metadata working, I only see a behaviour specification in code in Autofac examples but trying to get it from web.config

Comment: Yes, I'm getting metadata correctly. I think that using the property: <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/> is enough!

Comment: Hi, how are you hosting your service, I am using IISExpress but get error that says "he service 'xxxx' configured for WCF is not registered with the Autofac container." I added a class with AppInitialize in my App_code folder but it does not hit this code when I browse. Any ideas?

Comment: I've implemented the Application_Start event in Global.asax to initialize the Autofac Container. The services (.svc) use AutofacServiceHostFactory to instantiate: <%@ ServiceHost    Service="xxx.xxx.IService, library"
    Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf" %>